# Accessing facebook photos/albums without an access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Why can some folks access their facebook photos/albums by using the following endpoint:

**www.facebook.com/facebookID/albums**

But, when I try to access MY albums in this manner I get an error prompting me to use an access_token.

**www.facebook.com/facebookID/albums?access_token=GFDGTRDSVGRDWVSGRDESVGRDSVGDFRSGRDSGDRSGRD....**

It (obviously) works fine when I use a token but, I'd like to be able to allow access without a token... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing photos is privileged you require an access token from either photos or friends_photos to make the request successfully.

The reason some people may be able to access albums or photos without the token appended to the url is because it was previously requested and is currently stored.

You should always provide an access token in these requests.

see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

for reference it states:

```
To read an Album you need

 - Any valid access token if it is public and belongs to a Page
 - The user_photos permission if it belongs to a User The friends_photos
 - permission if it belongs to a User's friend
```